# D3.js dynamically switching between number and dollar formats on tick marks

Tags: d3.js

I have data that show both the number of items sold as well as the value of those items. I have a dynamic and interactive line chart that switches between the two data sets. I'd like to format the tick marks on the axis so that dollar signs appear on the axis where appropriate.

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y)
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","Yaxis")
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.number  }) ]);

svg.selectAll(".Yaxis")
.transition()
.duration(3000)
.call(yAxis);`
```

The entire pen is available here: https://codepen.io/cyrusobrien/full/NWdPRLp

Answer (score 0):

Replace D3 **tickFormat** with your custom one:

```
const d3Format = d3.format(".2s");
const customFormat = value => `$${d3Format(value)}`;
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y)
  .tickFormat(customFormat)
```